# A header in page_navbar adds a lot of white space to the Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, bslib

I am trying to add my company's logo to a Shiny app using `bslib` and `page_navbar`.  I am using the `header` argument to `page_navbar` to supply an `imageOutput` ui element.

This does add the image to the page, however it also adds a lot of white space below the navbar.

How can I accomplish this without all the white space?

Here is a minimal example.  The image link will be broken in this example, but the problem is apparent.  Thank you.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(bslib)

ui <- page_navbar(
  title = "test navbar",
  header = imageOutput("logo"),
  nav_panel("mtcars", DTOutput("mtcars")),
) 

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$logo <- renderImage(list(src = "broken", align = "right", height = 100, width = 100), deleteFile = FALSE)
  output$mtcars <- renderDT({mtcars})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imageOutput` has a `height` parameter whose default is set to `400px` (see `?imageOutput`). You can edit this parameter for reducing the whitespace between your `navbar` and your table. See the example below.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(bslib)

ui <- page_navbar(
    title = "test navbar",
    header = imageOutput("logo", height = "150px"),
    nav_panel("mtcars", DTOutput("mtcars")),
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$logo <-
        renderImage(list(
            src = "broken",
            align = "right",
            height = 100,
            width = 100
        ),
        deleteFile = FALSE)
    output$mtcars <- renderDT({
        mtcars
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]